# Crossbrowser media player

Tags: html, cross-browser, cross-platform, media-player, .mov

Is there any media player solution that will play audio and video files in Firefox,Chrome, Safari and IE.
I've tried MediaElementJS but it fails on .mov.  This project has clients uploading a movie file and there can only be one version of each file.  I can programatically change the code for each type of file and the user's OS/browser but I still couldnt get .mov's to download progressively.
What am I missing here?  I'm not very familiar with media file types.  Just wondering if anyone had any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [JW Player](http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/). It's highly configurable. Best combination is with a real streaming server provider. If you want to let your clients switch to different positions in your media files it might best work that you "normalize" all your different media types to one format (converting them after the upload) - be it .flv/flash - and focus on one player like the above. The files could be streamed with modules from webservers like nginx or lighttpd - but a real provider like [Bits on the Run](http://www.bitsontherun.com/) will convert most of the files for you very easily and handle the streaming more reliably.

Comment: Sadly they have to stay in their original format - any feature other than play/pause volume isn't terribly necessary.  I will look into JW Player.  Thank you for your response!

Comment: Ended up going with JW Player and it seems to be working great.  Thanks!